# Hide a Control Box in Excel

Tags: macos, vba, microsoft-excel-2011, microsoft-excel-2016

I have some radio buttons in Excel (2011 Mac), and they are grouped by a Group Box.

I want to make the Group Box invisible. I searched on the internet and found that I could do that with VBA by entering:

```
ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Visible = False
```

in the VBA window that corresponds to the relevant worksheet. I did that but there seems to be no difference. Do I have to do something else to activate the change?

Comment: When do you want the group box to be hidden? Is there an event you want to trigger this? Or do you just want to do this as a one off?

Comment: @DavidPostill For future reference, [mac] is reserved for Apple hardware questions.

Comment: @Excellll Got it ;)

Comment: I just want the group boxes to be hidden always. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call it out specifically by name

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group Box 1").Visible = False
```

Make sure `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` e.g.

```
Sub hidethings()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group Box 2").Visible = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you have a bunch that you want to hide you can do something like this -

```
Sub tellme()
Dim thing As Shape
For Each thing In ActiveSheet.Shapes
 If thing.FormControlType = xlGroupBox Then
   thing.Visible = msoFalse
 End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I put 'Application.ScreenUpdating = True' in the same Editor window?

Comment: If you haven't turned it off you don't need to turn it on. But it goes in the same function or routine that you're running.

Comment: I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong, but as you can see in this screenshot, I have entered "ActiveSheet.Shapes("Group Box 62").Visible = False", but the Group Box 62 is still visible: http://snag.gy/rNM4w.jpg

Comment: Make sure it's the right name. You could do `for each shape in activesheet.shapes debug.print shape.name next`

Comment: The box is always still visible. I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Try putting a groupbox on a different workbook and see if you can hide it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34260/discussion-between-user1551817-and-raystafarian).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've entered one line of VBA code but have not placed it in a subroutine that can be executed. Hence, what you've done has no effect.

Try the following:

1. Open the VBA editor pane by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.
2. In the window that opens insert a new module by clicking through `Insert` > `Module`.
3. In the text box that appears, paste the following:

   ```
   Sub HideBoxes()
   ActiveSheet.GroupBoxes.Visible = False
   End Sub
   ```
4. Place the cursor anywhere inside the code and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute the code.

This should hide any group boxes on the active sheet.